# edit joomla components to create custom fields

Tags: php, joomla2.5, custom-fields

I wanted to make a joomla module with multiselect dropdownlist that will contain menu categories(like main menu,product menu, etc). After some researching i found out that for select we use some components and edit/overide them.I found an example with a dropdown of contacts that he used this xml code:

```
<field
name="catid"
type="category"
extension="com_contact"
multiple="true"
default=""
size="10"
label="JCATEGORY">
```

and this helper code:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_contact/models','ContactModel');
class modtestHelper
{
public function getList(&$params)
{
$app= JFactory::getApplication();
$db= JFactory::getDbo();
$model= JModel::getInstance('Contacts', 'ContactModel',array('ignore_request' => true));
$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appPaParams);
$model->setState('list.start', 0);
$model->setState('list.limit', (int) $params->get('count',5));
$model->setState('filter.published', 1);
$model->setState('list.select', 'a.id, a.name, a.catid' . ', a.address, a.suburb, a.postcode, a.state,a.telephone ' .', a.published, a.access, a.ordering, a.language'.', a.publish_up, a.publish_down');
$access = !JComponentHelper::getParams('com_contact')->get('show_noauth');
$authorised =JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));
$model->setState('filter.access', $access);
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', array()));
$model->setState('filter.language',$app->getLanguageFilter());
$model->setState('list.ordering', 'ordering');
$model->setState('list.direction', 'ASC');
$items = $model->getItems();
return $items;
}
}
```

At the first glance i though that com_contacts was the component for every dropdownlist altough after i debuged this http://pastebin.com/m9kFpmvs (it was a big one so i pasted here instead)

```
$model= JModel::getInstance('Contacts', 'ContactModel',array('ignore_request' => true));
```

I see that it has custom field like theese:

```
[0] => id
[1] => a.id
[2] => name
[3] => a.name
```

SO what i need now:
As far i can imagine the com_contact wont be useful to me, i wanted to ask if someone knows a different component that i could use to make a multiselect dropdownlist for menus,and if a guru could explain me please how exactly the code that i found at the example fetches the results when i dont see any query being executed.It connects to DB

```
$db= JFactory::getDbo();
```

but i cant find any query at all.
Thanks in advance